# Method still adding specified data, which should've added once

Tags: android, database, sqlite

that i have to change some methods from my program, because it didn't work that as i want to. I have a method which should add data to database if another method will find out there's missing data in specific table, then program should populate spinner by this data. I really don't know what is going on, i've checked my db multiple times, and it contain data,which should be added only one time.

Here's some code:

this method have to check, if there's any data in specifed table

```
public void checkDB() {
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    if (db.shouldPopulate()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Spinners will be populated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.insertBodyParts();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Spinners are already populated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this method have to load data from database into specifed spinner

```
public void loadBodyPartsMF() {
    List<String> data = db.getBodyParts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    firstBodyPartMonday.setAdapter(adapter);

    firstBodyPartMonday.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            mondayFirstBodyPartString = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here's methods from database that should add and get data from table

```
public boolean insertBodyParts(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_CALF,"calf");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_LEGS,"legs");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_BACK,"back");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_SHOULDERS,"shoulders");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_BICEPS,"biceps");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_TRICEPS,"triceps");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_CHEST,"chest");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_ABS,"abs");
    contentValues.put(EXERCISES_FOREARM,"forearm");

    return db.insert(EXERCISES_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues) != -1;
}



public List<String> getBodyParts() {
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + EXERCISES_TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(2));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(3));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(4));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(5));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(6));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(7));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(8));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(9));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return labels;
}
```

And here is how i've made this table etc.

```
private static final String EXERCISES_TABLE_NAME = "Body_parts";
private static final String EXERCISES_CALF = "Calf";
private static final String EXERCISES_LEGS = "Legs";
private static final String EXERCISES_BACK = "Back";
private static final String EXERCISES_SHOULDERS = "Shoulders";
private static final String EXERCISES_BICEPS = "Biceps";
private static final String EXERCISES_TRICEPS = "Triceps";
private static final String EXERCISES_CHEST = "Chest";
private static final String EXERCISES_ABS = "Abs";
private static final String EXERCISES_FOREARM = "Forearm";



        db.execSQL("create table " + EXERCISES_TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + EXERCISES_CALF + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_LEGS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_BACK + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_SHOULDERS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_BICEPS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_TRICEPS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_CHEST + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_ABS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_FOREARM + " TEXT)");


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EXERCISES_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Why it's still adding the same data, if it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the only uniqueness that has been defined is for the ID column, which is being automatically generated as no value is specified (as is the normal/expected usage for an ID column).

You would need to add uniqueness by explicitly or implicitly defining an index or indexes dependant upon your requirements for uniqueness.

For example if you wanted to allow all but an exact duplicate then you could either define a composite index for all the columns except the ID column.

e.g. you could use

```
db.execSQL("create table " + 
EXERCISES_TABLE_NAME + 
" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + EXERCISES_CALF + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_LEGS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_BACK + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_SHOULDERS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_BICEPS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_TRICEPS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_CHEST + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_ABS + " TEXT," + EXERCISES_FOREARM + " TEXT, UNIQUE(" + 
EXERCISES_CALF + "," + 
EXERCISES_LEGS + "," +
EXERCISES_BACK + "," +
EXERCISES_SHOULDERS + "," +
EXERCISES_BICEPS + "," +
EXERCISES_TRICEPS + "," +
EXERCISES_CHEST + "," + 
EXERCISES_ABS + "," +
EXERCISES_FOREARM + 
"))");
```

Or you could explicitly create an index using the above columns [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE INDEX](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

If you wanted fewer columns to determine the uniqueness then simple include fewer columns.